# Finds the last value in a collection that matches some criterion, But if I wnat the last value?

Tags: groovy, jira

The find method finds the **first** value in a collection that matches some criterion.

But I want finds the **last** value in a collection that matches some criterion.

Is there has another method to do?

If not, how can I do?

Beacuse in Jira,I want a field to show the last date of status chang to "SIT Done"

But use the code,it's just get the first date.
I have no idea how to edit code to show the last date.

Can someone tell me?

Below is my code

```
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor


def changeHistoryManager = ComponentAccessor.getChangeHistoryManager()
def created = changeHistoryManager.getChangeItemsForField(issue, "status").find { 
    it.toString == "SIT Done"
}?.getCreated()

def createdTime = created?.getTime()

createdTime ? new Date(createdTime).format("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm") : null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `reverse()`:

```
def created = changeHistoryManager.getChangeItemsForField(issue, "status").reverse().find { 
    it.toString() == "SIT Done"
}?.created
```

Comment: Or `findAll` and take `results[-1]`

Comment: thousands ways to skin a cat, yay! @tim_yates beware of IOOB exception